# Scraping Tabular(Equity historical) data from the nse website

Tags: r, web-scraping, finance

I'm trying to webscrape equity historical data from the nse website :
https://www.nseindia.com/products/content/equities/equities/eq_security.htm

I Tried to web scrape data data for a company(symbol name) named RELIANCE for the range(time period) past 2 weeks and transfer the contents to a CSV file

```
library(rvest)

url <- "https://www.nseindia.com/products/dynaContent/common/productsSymbolMapping.jsp?symbol=RELIANCE&segmentLink=3&symbolCount=2&series=ALL&dateRange=15days&fromDate=&toDate=&dataType=PRICEVOLUMEDELIVERABLE"
page_html <- read_html(url)
data <- html_nodes(page_html, "p")
data <- html_text(data)

write.csv(data$data, "scrapedData.csv", row.names=FALSE)
```

Its Says character(empty)

I know that there is an option to download the csv file there in the website but i want an automated R Script for getting the data.

I know that there are other packages such as quantmod are present for getting historical stock data but i require from this website as it has useful information such as TTQ,Turnover,etc.

Comment: point 12 https://www.nseindia.com/wap/mobile_termsofuse.htm scrapping not permitted

Comment: You can refer `nser` package to download the historical bhavcopy. https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/nser/index.html

Answer (score 4):

why reinvent the wheel?

you can use **nsepy** python module. 
https://github.com/swapniljariwala/nsepy

there are similar alternatives exist.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to use this:

```
from nsepy import get_history
from datetime import date
data = get_history(symbol="SBIN", start=date(2015,1,1), end=date(2015,1,31))
```